# Is there a way in Jira to allow the screen attachment screen to be hooked up to a new issue screen?

Tags: jira

In Jira, while in the basic view issue page, there is a drop-down under "More..." for "Attach screenshot". Is there any way to attach the attach screenshot fields to a screen such as the Comment screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Wiki markup to display thumbnails of attachments inside comments.

Answer (score 0):

That is configurable in the screen options( Attachment field )

If you want a nicer gui, you may install the "Drag and Drop Attachment" plugin ...